# How to get User Details for who importing the tabular in to excel

Tags: ssis, ssas

Currently i am doing POC on tabular hitting process.

Here, I need to get the details of the User who importing the tabular model in to excel. I am unable to find the approach to get the details of the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the below approaches to identify the users who are connecting and querying the SSAS cube.

- [using SQL Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/introduction-to-monitoring-analysis-services-with-sql-server-profiler)
- [Using Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/monitor-analysis-services-with-sql-server-extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15)

Extended events are generally preferred approach for tracing, as it is less obstructive.

Comment: Thanks, I got an idea.
Please can you provide the process to implement in tabular

Comment: Read about Vertipaq related events. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/trace-events/analysis-services-trace-events & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/trace-events/query-processing-events-data-columns

Comment: Sure, Thank you so much

Comment: I tried the above approach. It is fine. I have one doubt.
How can i enable the option in Session Name -> Reports -> Custom Reports